# Webpack loads from the wrong URL when the path changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm writing a react app and everything works fine when I navigate to `localhost:3000`, but when I try to go to `localhost:3000/foo/page`, I get an error message that tells me localhost:3000/foo/bundle.js cannot be loaded.

To me, this looks like a problem with Webpack looking in the wrong place for bundle.js, but I'm not sure.  How do I get the app to always look at `localhost:3000` for bundle.js?

This is some of my webpack config.

```
var TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
var APP_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'app');
var BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'dist');

process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;
var common = {
    entry: APP_PATH,

    output: {
        path: BUILD_PATH,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                include: APP_PATH
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
                include: APP_PATH
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
                include: APP_PATH
            },
            {
                test: /\.ico$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
                include: APP_PATH
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'foobar',
            template: path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'index.html'),
            favicon: path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'images', 'favicon.ico')
        })
    ]
};

if (TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(common, {
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
                    include: APP_PATH
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true,
            inline: true,
            port: 3000,
            progress: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `output.publicPath: '/'` to your webpack config.

```
output: {
  path: BUILD_PATH,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

HtmlWebpackPlugin most probably generates the file which have:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Setting up `output.publicPath: '/'` will make it:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

From [Webpack Config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) page:

> output.publicPath
>
> The publicPath specifies the public URL address of
>   the output files when referenced in a browser. For loaders that embed
>    or  tags or reference assets like images, publicPath is
>   used as the href or url() to the file when it’s different then their
>   location on disk (as specified by path). This can be helpful when you
>   want to host some or all output files on a different domain or on a
>   CDN. The Webpack Dev Server also takes a hint from publicPath using it
>   to determine where to serve the output files from. As with path you
>   can use the [hash] substitution for a better caching profile.

Comment: Think there's a typo in *publicPath = '/'* should be publicPath : '/'

Comment: BTW, thanks a bunch. This was the problem I was having. publicPath needs to be set in order for require.ensure to work.

Comment: @JoseA yep updated. Thank you for spotting it! No worries mate!

Comment: In laravel mix just add the `mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/'
    }
});`

Comment: Thank yooouuuuuuuuu! There's not a single mention in `url-loader` docs that `publicPath` would get my asset URLs working.